# Align table vertical

Tags: html, css

The below table aligns horizontally as designed. Can anyone suggest a way of aligning the table vertically when reducing screen size for mobile?

```html
<table class="rides-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30 miles</td>
    <td>70 miles</td>
    <td>50 miles</td>
    <td>40 miles</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Beginner</td>
    <td>Advanced</td>
    <td>Intermediate</td>
    <td>Beginner</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem often.
But I don't believe it's a problem to be solved with development. The problem with tables on mobile is a UX issue.

How we usually solve it is transposing the table. Using your example
:

```
<html>
    <table class="rides-table desktop">
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>30 miles</td>
            <td>70 miles</td>
            <td>50 miles</td>
            <td>40 miles</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Beginner</td>
            <td>Advanced</td>
            <td>Intermediate</td>
            <td>Beginner</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table class="rides-table mobile">
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <td>Beginner</td>
            <td>30 miles</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <td>Advanced</td>
            <td>70 miles</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <td>Intermediate</td>
            <td>50 miles</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <td>Beginner</td>
            <td>40 miles</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

I use the `.desktop` and `.mobile` class to hide and show elements in media query.